# How can I count waypoints between a curve?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, bezier-curve

I have curve that is drawn between point A and B. I want to divide this curve to 100 smaller waypoints. How can I determine what these 100 waypoints are as coordinates, when I only know points A and B?

Comment: What form does the curve between A and B take? Is it a straight line, an arc of a circle, a cubic spline (the last two will require additional 'control points' to be specified - what are they?) or something else?

Comment: Curve can take form of arc of cricle.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is just to divide the interval in $x$ into $101$ intervals.  So if $A=(a_x,a_y)$ and $B=(b_x,b_y)$, use $a_x+i(b_x-a_x)/101$ and find the corresponding $y$ coordinate for $i$ from $1$ to $100$.